# Covalent vs Ionic bond in Silicon dioxide

Tags: bond

I was wondering why silicon dioxide tends to be a covalent bond instead of an ionic bond. Based on lewis structures, the octet rule seems to work for silicon dioxide so shouldn't it also be an ionic bond?

Comment: Losing four electrons to form a $\ce{Si^{4+}}$ is quite unlikely and requires a lot of energy to do so.

Comment: How does covalent bonding require less energy?

Answer (score -2):

Because silicon and oxygen are nonmetals on the period, hence they form covalent bonds. For ionic bonding, it must be between a metal and a nonmetal.

Comment: You might want to add a word or two about electronegativity.

Comment: "It must be a metal and a nonmetal", like ammonium chloride?